# Do I need to have a certain amount of Rep before being invited to a Area51 beta

Tags: support, area-51

I've committed (I think) to an Area51 proposal that is about to go into beta and I'm wondering if I need to have a certain amount of Rep before I get access to that beta area?

Comment: Reputation where exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, no:

If you have signed up and committed then you will be one of the founders. You will develop rep there once it is live, but you will start there with 1 (or 101 if you have sufficient rep on other SE sites)